# Laravel 5 and AngularJS Data

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I'm implementing `AngularJS` with `Laravel` and having some issues. My codes:

**Route:**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
   return view('angular');
});

Route::get('/test', function () {
   return User::all();
});
```

**HTML/JS (test.blade.php):**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="userCtrl"> 

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in user">
    @{{ x.email + ', ' + x.name }}
  </li>
</ul>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('userCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("/test")
    .success(function(response) {
        $scope.user = response.data; 
        console.log(response);
    });
});
</script>
```

Whenever I run this I get a blank page but in my console:
[image]

Am I missing something here? Thank you.

Comment: Yes. I want it to show in the blade @K.Toress

Comment: That should work as expected, I cannot understand the problem. Do you have any errors in console?

Comment: @Michelem, I'm not getting any errors in the console. Maybe I need some angularjs routing?

Comment: Try to look at the source code of the html output to see if you are getting the correct files.

Comment: What do you mean @Michelem?

Comment: Check you are getting test.blade.php and not something else

Comment: The thing is Im not rendering the data to the test.blade.php I think

Comment: I think it should be `$scope.user = response;`

Comment: @Michelem, you are right. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

check in console if it is returned valid in success: `console.log(data);`. 
If yes try: `$scope.user = angular.fromJson(data);`